# Android SQLite - Getting no such table error (code 1)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am developing an Android app for a bus schedule. I have a SQLite database with the stops and times, but I am currently having a nightmare trying to access it. I googled this issue, but I couldn't find a solution.

I have built a `DataBaseHelper` class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` with the code as follows:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH;

    private static String DB_NAME = "BagesExpress_def";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    private final Context myContext;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null,1);
        this.myContext = context;
        this.DB_PATH = this.myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getAbsolutePath();
    }

    public void createDatabase() throws IOException{
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            Log.v("EXISTS", "dbExists");
        }else{
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try{
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e){
                throw new Error ("Error copying data");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }catch(SQLiteException e){

        }

        if(checkDB!=null){
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        String outFilename = DB_PATH;

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);

        byte[] buffer = new byte [1024];
        int length;

        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer,0,length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
        String myPath = DB_PATH;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    public synchronized void close() {
        if(myDataBase!=null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db){

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        if(newVersion>oldVersion)
            try{
                copyDataBase();
            }
            catch(IOException ioe){

            }
    }

    public List<Viatge> getViatges(int horaSortida, int paradaSortida, int paradaArribada){

        Log.v("DBPATH",DB_PATH);
        List<Viatge> viatges = new ArrayList<Viatge>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT t1.run, t1.parada, t2.parada,t1.hora,t2.hora FROM directesDirBarna t1, directesDirBarna t2 \n" +
                "WHERE (t1.run = t2.run AND t1.parada = "+ paradaSortida +" AND t2.parada = " + paradaArribada +") \n" +
                "AND t1.Hora > "+ horaSortida +" AND t2.Hora <> '';";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                Viatge viatge = new Viatge();
                viatge.setParadaSortida(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
                viatge.setParadaArribada(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
                viatge.setHoraSortida(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
                viatge.setHoraArribada(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)));

                viatges.add(viatge);
            } while(cursor.moveToNext());

        }
        return viatges;
    }
}
```

Inside a `testSQL` Activity, I am using the following code:

```
 public class SqlTest extends Activity {
    private DataBaseHelper myDBHelper;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sql_test);

        Button sqlButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SQLBtn);
        sqlButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myDBHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

                try {
                    myDBHelper.openDataBase();
                }
                catch(SQLException sqle){
                }

                myDBHelper.getViatges(1000,1,10);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_sql_test, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

When I press the button to fetch the database, I get the following  error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table:
>   directesDirBarna (code 1)

Despite this table existing in my database.

I suspect that this happens because my code can't find the DataBase so it creates a blank one and thus it can't find anything in it, but I can't find where this happens.

Can anyone illuminate my way? Thanks a lot.

Edit: This was solved. I used this https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper, uninstalled app from my device, made a clean build and now it works.

Comment: Your MySQL query looks very questionable. Can you please elaborate what you're expecting to get from the query and provide your MySQL table structure?

Comment: @D3LIC1OU5 yeah i realised that the query isn't giving me the results that i thought first, but still that doesn't cause the issue, i would get a wrong output from querying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the issue is related to the query sql itself :

String selectQuery = "SELECT t1.run, t1.parada, t2.parada,t1.hora,t2.hora FROM `directesDirBarna t1, directesDirBarna t2` \n" +
                "WHERE (t1.run = t2.run AND t1.parada = "+ paradaSortida +" AND t2.parada = " + paradaArribada +") \n" +
                "AND t1.Hora > "+ horaSortida +" AND t2.Hora <> '';";

you are using the same table twice ...

Comment: Mm no, the query is working perfectly, i tested it several times.